# Does my age depend on the current timezone?

Tags: legal, timezones

If I turn, say, 18 at home, and immediately travel westwards into a different time zone where it's still the previous day, will I be legally 17 or 18 there?

And if 17, how would that affect e.g. any rules that would require me to be of age for that specific journey (can't think of any specifics, and yes this is getting rather academical now).

This question is about the legal aspects, not the practical side of how to actually do it.

Comment: Cannot happen more than once, see the canonical question for details

Comment: I'm not interested in more than once situations. Once shouldn't be too implausible?

Comment: It's the same answer regardless...

Comment: In practical terms Calchas' answer is probably applicable 99.9% of the time. I could imagine it being fought in court if you, say, committed a major crime and extradition to be tried as an adult was at stake. Hopefully you're not planning to murder anyone.

Comment: Should be moved to Law SE.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm long past 17/18 so it doesn't really influence my murderous plans one way or the other :)

Comment: There are some uninhabited islands to the East of the date line that are 2 days behind NZ's date for one hour per day during NZ summer daylight saving. It would take some fairly rapid travelling (probably military class) to make any real (or unreal) use of this. I think :-).  | Alaska cheats and runs on Ca time or would otherwise be a prime candidate. |All of China notionally runs on Beijing time (don'y tell HQ that this is not always followed) so the Western side is hours different to its cross border neighbours. ...

Comment: ... If one of them did and one didn't use daylight saving you may be able to arrange some to and fro changes. And, the odds of anyone caring are vanishingly close to zero.

Comment: @GayotFow - See my China + daylight saving neighbour + non daylight saving neighbour for a possible multi change case :-).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will be 17 according to the local calendar.

No one checks your "Place of birth" when they ask for your age.

Comment: You've obviously never seen the John Travolta classic, *Phenomenon* (1996). ;-)